# Geometry nodes glowing points on surface of cube

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to create a simple animation where points are distributed on faces of the cube. Then I want to use icospheres as instances on points and give them star like look and bloom.

[image: overall looks like this]

Is there any way I can use two different mesh objects as instances for this cube? For example red and orange icospheres in proportion 1:2?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your first question (on this site you shouldn't ask several question in one question, please open other questions for additional questions, thank you):

if you mean like this:

[image]

you can use this node setup:

[image]

Give both icospheres in the collection some emission color and an emission color >1.

On EEVEE enable Bloom.

[image]

---- UPDATE ----

Solution for changed question:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have edited the original post. The solution works, could you please guide me, what would be the right node to connect to "instance index" to make the 1:2 proportion of objects with different colors?

Comment: i updated my answer.